# Why the output of this C program sticks?

Tags: c, search, binary

I am trying to make a program that counts the number of keywords present in the input similar to the example of Dennis Ritchie's The C Programming Language example in Section 6.3 Arrays of Structures.Here is my code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int binsearch(char *s, struct key mt[], int lim);
int getch(void);
void ungetch(int );
int getword(char *word, int lim);
struct key{
    int count;
    char *word;
}keys[] = { { 0, "break" }, { 0, "int" }, { 0, "return" } };

int main()
{
        int n;
    char word[20];
    while (getword(word, 20) != EOF)
        if (isalpha(word[0]))
        if ((n = binsearch(word, keys, 3)) >= 0)
            keys[n].count++;
        for (n = 0; n < 3; n++)
            if (keys[n].count>0)
            printf("%s count=%d", keys[n].word, keys[n].count);
    return 0;
}
int getword (char *word, int lim) 
{
    int c;
    char *w = word;
    while (isspace(c = getch()))
        ;
    if (c != EOF)
        *w++ = c;
    if (!isalpha(c)){
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }
    for (; --lim > 0;w++)
    if (!isalnum(*w = getch())){
        ungetch(*w);
        break;
    }
    *w = '\0';
    return word[0];
}
char buffer[400];
int t = 0;

int getch(void)
{
    return ((t == 0) ? getchar() : buffer[--t]);
}
void ungetch(int c)
{
    buffer[t++] = c;
}
int binsearch(char *s, struct key mt[], int lim)
{
    int cond;
    int min = 0;
    int max = lim - 1;
    int mid = (min + max) / 2;
    while (min <= max)
    {
        if ((cond = strcmp(s, mt[mid].word)) > 0)
            min = mid + 1;
        else if (cond < 0)
            max = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

On compiling this code in Visual Studio Express 2013 the Output Terminal only accepts the 1st line and on pressing enter nothing happens.Neither more data could be inputted nor any output comes.Please help me figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Change `"%s count=%d"` to `"%s count=%d\n"`.

Comment: What is `char buffer[400];` used for in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.I found what was the problem.Actually in binsearch function I defined mid=(min+max)/2 outside the while loop.